# How to get unbanned after a question-ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

When I try to ask a question, I see the below message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Is it possible to reverse this ban?

Comment: Did you see the help center?

Comment: Did you go to the help center, find the this very FAQ and *read* what it says?

Comment: Yes i read FAQ but i don't undestand how to remove ban?Can you explain me?

Comment: Did you actually pay attention to what it says? You know the bit about *"The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". Begin by fixing your existing posts;"* and the rest of that paragraph? Seriously. That is the *whole* answer. It is all you are going to get.

Comment: But i delete bad question?How to fix?

Comment: @Filip First, 1 bad question will NOT get you banned. You probably have 3 or more heavily downvoted, deleted questions.  Second, if you have the URL in your browser history, you can still view it, edit it, and undelete it. If not flag an existing post if yours and ask a mod to undelete your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) (bolding mine):

> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time: if you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways. Also, moderators cannot lift the ban by request.
>
> Before you do anything else, **fix your existing posts**! As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then **writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again.** But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

To add on to this, you can edit questions and answers.

Comment: Have a look at this account, he's only got one downvoted question out of 5 and no downvoted/upvoted answers. Maybe I cant see the rest...

Comment: Quality, not quantity :) more hard work should fix it

Comment: Rather than copying-and-pasting the answers from another question, why not just flag this one as a duplicate?

Comment: @CodyGray I figured I'd give the user a more personal experience rather than say "Nope, go find the answer yourself."

Comment: But you're not saying that. You're giving them a link to the answer. They don't have to find anything themselves.

Comment: I bolded stuff that might help, and I thought that it would be more friendly to do so instead of asking them to click on a duplicate link which takes them to the same place anyway.